# Bash OLD history with timestamp

Tags: bash

I know about "HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m/%d - %H:%M:%S: " but this will give me history with timestamp from present session to onward and all commands from previous history will have same but incorrect timestamp. 
Is there any way I can get let's say one week old history with proper timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't.

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/histtimeformat-does-not-show-correct-date-and-time-for-history?answertab=active#tab-top).

If you set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in bash your **new** entries get stored in the history file with a timestamp, older commands that don't have a timestamp (those before you ever set `HISTTIMEFORMAT`) will display one and the same date-time-stamp (I assume the one from the first entry found with a real timestamp).